# Gantt diagram generator from textual representation

Tags: linux, data-visualization, charts, plain-text, diagram

I am looking for command line utility to generate Gantt diagram from textual representation in **Graphviz** way or in the way that **Blockdiag** does. I'm aware of **Mermaid** and **NodeJS**, and I know that **Plantuml** is planning to add Gantt diagram implementation.

Something similar is possible achieve using **Gnuplot**, but the syntax is quite specific and complex ([have a look at this example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/master/demo/gantt.dem))

I want to do something like:

```
gantt source.txt > image.png
```

Is there any tool available now?

Comment: Here is [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/20820/linux-program-to-create-a-timeline-diagram)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reason why https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid.cli wouldn't work in your case. MIT licensed, it should allow you to save this into `gantt.txt`

```
gantt
    title A Gantt Diagram
    dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD
    section Section
    A task           :a1, 2014-01-01, 30d
    Another task     :after a1  , 20d
    section Another
    Task in sec      :2014-01-12  , 12d
    another task      : 24d
```

And this should give you the picture

```
mmdc -i gantt.txt -o image.png
```

[image: mermaid gantt]

The **Blockdiag** you've mentioned is also a Python library, and you could make a command line script with it.